# puppet enterprise installation error

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I am using puppet-enterprise-3.3.2-el-6-x86_64.tar.gz to install puppet enterprise, after installation I got

```
ERROR: Could not install required packages--this may be due to a network failure or incorrect repository
  settings. You must install the following packages before you can install Puppet Enterprise:
 pe-puppet-server and pe-rubycas-server
```

while I install I got

```
pe-httpd.worker is stopped.
```

Also I tried "service pe-httpd status" it shows

```
pe-httpd.worker is stopped.
```

I suspect due to this I got n/w failure error

I have done below validation
1) yum.log - No error message 
2) install_log.lastrun.$HOSTNAME - No error message. I have seen complete message.
3) puppet --version - shows 3.7.2 (Puppet Enterprise 3.7.0)
4) also I ran puppet apply -e 'notify { "Hello, world!": }' - it worked with out any error

I tried to install pe-puppet-server(just for my referrence)

```
yum install pe-puppet-server
```

got below message

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Package pe-puppet-server-3.6.2.14-1.pe.el6.noarch is obsoleted by pe-puppetserver-common-3.7.2.2-1.pe.el6.noarch which is already installed
Nothing to do
```

but in package folder I could not find pe-puppetserver-common-3.7.2.2-1.pe.el6.noarch.
Not sure how it get inatalled.

Also I grep "rmp -qa|grep pe-puppetserver-common-3.7.2.2-1.pe.el6.noarch" it shows pe-puppetserver-common-3.7.2.2-1.pe.el6.noarch.
I unstalled PE and done yum clean all. Again tried to re-install PE. Again getting same error.

The network failure or incorrect repository error is common.If not, please help me to resolve.

Also I try to install3.3.2 but why it shows 3.7 PE version please correct me if my understaning is wrong.

Comment: Well, so you do have a package that obsoletes one requirement, `pe-puppet-server`. What about `pe-rubycas-server`, have you tried installing that? - The `pe-httpd.worker` is a red herring, I think.

Comment: Yes. I tried installing pe-rubycas-server. getting same obsoleted error for package console. When I try to install, getting already installed nothing to do message.

Answer (score 3):

You already installed Puppet Enterprise 3.7 on this computer. You cannot downgrade to 3.3 using the installer.

Comment: Notsure whether PE3.7 already installed or not,but open source 3.7 already installed. I have uninstalled open sourece and installed puppet enterprise.

Comment: Your own output shows Puppet Enterprise 3.7 installed, before you tried to install PE 3.3.

Comment: NO. PE3.7 was not installed before in master. Because after I uninstalled PE 3.7 and run puppet --version, it will not show anything. Only I installed PE3.7 and version command it shows "3.7.2 (Puppet Enterprise 3.7.0)"

Comment: Your uninstallation was not complete, apparently. Yes, you may have gotten rid of the `puppet` binary. But the `pe-puppetserver-common` package lingers and causes issues. Make sure to remove all Puppet related packages before proceding.

Comment: Thanks. I sorted out the problem. It seems problem with repo, its pointing incorrectly. Thank you all for your responses.